# Curl website optimizing and selecting every other URL to be curled

Tags: php, curl, load-balancing

I am trying to balance load on the curled websites and use difference addresses on every other request call. Both examples have the same result but just running different servers. I would like to make my curl different url each time curl is used.

For example:

- 1st request uses 1st in a row url to curl,
- 2nd request uses 2nd in a row url to curl,
- 3rd request uses 1st in a row url to curl,
- 4th request uses 2nd in a row url to curl,

and so forth..

How could I achieve this result? thanks.

Comment: You could use modulus of n to determine which website to use in the array, n being the size of array

Comment: how would that look like in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned you could use the [modulo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator to determine which key to use.

It would look something like the following:

```
<?php
$urls = [
    'http://www.example.com',
    'http://www.example.com2',
];

$limit = 100;

for( $x=0; $x<=$limit; $x++ ){

    $key = $x % 2;//modulo

    $url = $urls[$key];

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: If in the loop, you actually dont need to close curl. You could use the same object and reset the params, like the url, and send again.

Comment: what is the limit value stands for ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know which request it is, the modulus operator can determine which position in an array to use. The array keys of 0 and 1 are just there for explanation purposes. Those are generated automatically.

The modulus operator is essentially the remainder after the first number is divided by the following number. So, when the request is 46 and there are 2 websites in the array, the remainder will be 0 since 46/2 is 23 with no remainder. With 3 websites, the 46/3 will be 15.3 repeating, meaning that the modulus will be 45 with a remainder of 1. returning 1, it will take the array value at position `1`.

For example, the request number is assumed:

```
// This should change/increment for you
 $requestCounter = 1;
 $arrayOfWebsites = array(
    0       =>  'http://website1.com',
    1       =>  'https://website2.com'
 );

 $websiteToBeUsed = $arrayOfWebsites[ $requestCounter % count( $arrayOfWebsites ) ];
 var_dump( $websiteToBeUsed );
 // Your code
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $websiteToBeUsed );
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: How can I determine which request it is? how could I make it random, or just to go somehow one after the other etc?

Comment: @mamachichi Unless you have it saved in a database, or if it is the same client sending requests you could keep the count on the client side. Otherwise, you could just get a random number within the range of the `$arrayOfWebsites`